# How to train-test split and cross-validate in surprise?

Tags: python, dataset, cross-validation

I wrote the following code below which works:

```
from surprise.model_selection import cross_validate

cross_validate(algo,dataset,measures=['RMSE', 'MAE'],cv=5, verbose=False, n_jobs=-1)
```

However when I do this: (notice the trainset is passed here in cross_validate instead of whole dataset)

```
from surprise.model_selection import train_test_split
trainset, testset = train_test_split(dataset, test_size=test_size)
cross_validate(algo, trainset, measures=['RMSE', 'MAE'],cv=5, verbose=False, n_jobs=-1)
```

It gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Trainset' object has no attribute 'raw_ratings'
```

I looked it up and 
[Surprise documentation](https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/trainset.html) says that Trainset objects are not the same as dataset objects, which makes sense.

However, the documentation does not say how to convert the trainset to dataset.

My question is:
1. Is it possible to convert Surprise Trainset to surprise Dataset?
2. If not, what is the correct way to train-test split the whole dataset and cross-validate?

Comment: Hi. Programming issues are off-topic here. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details. You can ask this type of question on Stack Overflow or Data Science SE. I will migrate this question to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

2. From my understanding, cross-validate will perform the trainset(s)/testset(s) splits for you. So your first line of code is correct and will split into 5 folds(cv=5). Each fold will be the test for the other 4 (train).

If you wanted a simple train/test set, see [this example from the docs](https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html#train-test-split-py).